# Postgresql grant not successful

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am creating a function in postgres which is created but does not have the permissions to be accessed by the application. It is giving me

> WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"

I restarted with "open as administrator" option, this time I got the following error.

> ERROR:  must be owner of function

Here is my function

```
-- FUNCTION: traffic.get_user_route_folders_new()

--DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS traffic.get_user_route_folders_new();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new(
)
RETURNS json
LANGUAGE 'sql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
SELECT row_to_json(t) 
FROM  (
    SELECT id, name, parent_folder_id
    FROM traffic.here_traffic_route_folders 
) t
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new()
OWNER TO bcadmin;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new() TO PUBLIC;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new() TO bcadmin;
```

when I try to delete function again I get

> ERROR:  must be owner of function xyz

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but that function can certainly be executed by any PostgreSQL user. Perhaps the user is lacking the `USAGE` privilege on the schema.

Comment: Offtopic: Why a function? You could do the same using a view

Answer (score 1):

The error msg shows that you're attempting to change the function's ownership or delete it—actions that are restricted to the function's owner.You must grant the PUBLIC role the EXECUTE privilege on the function in order to resolve the issue. Try the following SQL statement to achieve this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new() TO PUBLIC;
```

You must either be the function's owner or have the DROP FUNCTION access in order to delete the function. Therefore request that the function's owner give you the ability to DROP FUNCTION if you are not the function's owner.

Use the following SQL query to delete the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION traffic.get_user_route_folders_new();
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: What does "*have the DROP FUNCTION access*" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here was a bit tricky for me and could not be answered with the limited information I had provided. I was logged-in by user **samra** while I was running GRANT for a different user. In our environment **bcadmin** is production user while dev user was me, **samra**. To confuse things more, there was another user **test** that I tried and it only had drop function privileges available to both environments.!!